# Yocto include cmake project with custom steps

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, yocto, yocto-recipe

I am trying to include this simple cmake-based project to my image: https://github.com/MatrixOrbital/HTT-Utility

The steps to build in Linux are:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

I am trying to reproduce these steps within my Yocto recipe. The generated binary (./build/htt_util) should be installed in /usr/bin.

So far with the help of devtool and some manual tuning I ended up with this recipe:

```
LICENSE = "MIT & Unknown"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=ff75ee274f4c77abeee3db089083fec7 \
                    file://hidapi/LICENSE.txt;md5=7c3949a631240cb6c31c50f3eb696077"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/MatrixOrbital/HTT-Utility.git;protocol=https"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-Adding-ctype.patch;"

PATCHTOOL = "git"

# Modify these as desired
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "2045d5eacc67b89a02dafe41edfd032179333aee"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake

# Specify any options you want to pass to cmake using EXTRA_OECMAKE:
EXTRA_OECMAKE = ""

DEPENDS += "udev"
```

What should I add to my recipe to achieve the goal of generating a binary and installing into /usr/bin?

I have been trying to play with:

```
do_configure() {
    ...
}

do_compile() {
    ...
}

do_install() {
    ...
}
```

But so far I did not manage to do anything useful.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
do_install() {
    install -m 0644 mybinary ${D}${bindir}
}

FILES_${PN} = " \
    ${bindir} \
"
```